# Gradle build failure (Build failed with an exception)

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I´m getting the erro below, when building my app

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- Where:
  Initialization script 'C:\Users\Diego\AppData\Local\Temp\ijresolvers6.gradle' line: 268
- What went wrong:
  Could not compile initialization script 'C:\Users\Diego\AppData\Local\Temp\ijresolvers6.gradle'.

> startup failed:
> initialization script 'C:\Users\Diego\AppData\Local\Temp\ijresolvers6.gradle': 268: unexpected char: '' @ line 268, column 106.
> sk.path, 'DEBUG_SERVER_PATH=C:\Users\Die

Answer (score 0):

try placing \ backlash before special characters, such as apostrophes.

Comment: The file is auto-generated so, i cant. Else, there is no apostrophes in the path, only the path separators...

Comment: The problem seems to be from your gradle file, perhaps you have an error there?,recheck both your app and module gradle files, if nothing, then open and close project :/